Updating local dev for CiviCRM and Drupal updates causes crash - "The "request_path" plugin does not exist
I did a routine local update today and moved from CiviCRM 5.73 and Drupal 10.2.6, to CiviCRM 5.74.4 and Drupal 10.3.0.
All was fine until I updated the Drupal database:
    2024-06-24 18:13:05 [Mon Jun 24 17:13:05.315115 2024] [php:notice]
 [pid 21] [client 172.20.0.1:53038] Uncaught PHP Exception
 Drupal\\Component\\Plugin\\Exception\\PluginNotFoundException: 
"The "request_path" plugin does not exist. 
Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\\rules\\Core\\ConditionManager are:
 response_code, rules_path_has_alias, rules_node_is_of_type,
 rules_node_is_promoted, rules_node_is_published,
 rules_data_is_empty, rules_node_is_sticky,
 rules_entity_is_of_bundle, rules_list_contains,
 rules_data_comparison, rules_entity_has_field, 
rules_list_count_is, rules_entity_field_access,
 rules_user_has_role, rules_user_is_blocked,
 rules_text_comparison, rules_entity_is_of_type, 
rules_path_alias_exists, rules_entity_is_new, webform,
 civicrm_entity_contact_in_group, 
civicrm_contact_id_drupal_user_exists, 
civicrm_entity_drupal_user_exists" at
/var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php line 53, 
referer: https://mysite/update.php/results

I'm not sure where to start looking.  The error refers to a missing plugin but nothing has changed in essence.  Has something been deprecated?  The PHP version 8.1.2, Drush is 12.5.2.

It looks like you have drupal rules enabled and in 10.3 it doesn't like request_path. See https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2024-06-20/update-to-1030-throws-the-request_path-plugin-does-not-exist

Thanks Demerit, a life saver - how I did not find that from searching before I posted here I'll never know...  In terms of understanding the error message, it looked like a whole load of modules were aggrieved and not just Rules. Thanks again

Fortunately, it only looks like we need Rules for the Quiz module.  I have been looking at the ECA Module (https://www.drupal.org/project/eca) recently and it looks like it might be a Rules replacement for anybody looking at moving away from Rules.  This may be a big migration but it may help some
